# Suspend Breaking Shell

Tags: c, shell, signals

I am currently writing a program in C that will (to a limited degree), mimic command prompt or terminal. So far it can run commands, knows how to ID internal commands, and also understands CTRL + C to stop a running process without killing the shell, but what I can't seem to get to work is CTRL + Z (which would suspend a process using SIGTSTP as shown below) (Where taskPID is the current process ID after forking). If I call CTRL + C on a running process, it will display the message, and return to the shell prompt (which is a while loop in main), If I call CTRL + Z, it hangs and shows an endless blinking cursor and I lose control of the Shell. Any ideas would be appreciated, as I am stuck on this one.

```
void
sigint_handler (int sig)
{
    printf("Process[%d] was Terminated Suddenly by User via (CTRL + C)\n",taskPID);
    kill(-taskPID, SIGINT);
}
```

```
void
sigtstp_handler (int sig)
{
  printf("Process[%d] was Suspended by User via (CTRL + Z)\n",taskPID);
  kill(-taskPID, SIGTSTP);
}
```

Comment: "*Any ideas would be appreciated*" about exactly what please?

Comment: Why ctrl +z breaks the program, but ctrl + c works fine?

Answer (score 1):

Ctrl-Z causes the terminal driver to send SIGSTOP to the foreground process group. This signal cannot be caught or ignored. The only way to prevent your *shell* to be stopped is to dodge the signal: once forked, the (parent) shell must change the process group, while leaving the child in the original.

Start with `man tcsetpgrp`, and `man setpgid`.

As a side note, `printf` is not signal safe. Don't use it in the signal handler.